# Detect orientation change in a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uipickerviewcontroller

Im trying to detect orientation changes in a UIImagePickerController (it inherits from UINavigationController : UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject) and I tried override the method `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` in UIViewController but no success...

any tips?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclassing UIImagePickerController is not supported!

> This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Maybe you could register for [`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` from `UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification) and use this?

Comment: Be aware that device orientation changes contain two more constants than interface orientation (namely: face up and face down) - you have to remember the last orientation you had (portrait/landscape) and ignore the face up/down changes to know which interface orientation you're actually in.

Comment: Unfortunately if the device's orientation is locked the notifications are no longer posted, but the camera interface is still being updated. Did you find a way around this?

Comment: A further issue is that the device orientation does not necessarily match the camera orientation.

Answer (score 2):

This is too late to answer here, but I'm expanding @Adam Woś answer,

Before presenting `UIImagePickerController`,

```
UIImagePickerController *controllerObject = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
...
...
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
...
...
[self presentViewController:controllerObject animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]];
}

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@".....landscape.....");
    }
    else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@".....portrait.....");
    }
}
```

When `UIImagePickerController` get dismiss don't forget,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Also note that, as per @FelixLam comment on @Adam Woś answer,

> if device orientation is locked then notifications no longer posted.

To handle this situation, one need to implement `CoreMotion` (alternative `UIAccelerometer` iOS < 6.0) to detect that device orientation is locked or not. Here's the blog for `UIAccelerometer` http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation/ and this is for `CoreMotion` https://github.com/tastyone/MotionOrientation You'll have to kick some logic to check this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From the official UIImagePickerController documentation:

> **Important:** The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. In iPhone OS 3.1 and later, you can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.